# Rails - How to set persistent randomized cookies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to set a cookie system on my app, so everytime a new user arrive, he gets a cookie with a random number (token). I want my user to have a token so that every time the user save an item, his token is also saved in the item database, so my app can check how many items this user saved.

I tried to write my application controller like this : if there are no cookies stocked, a cookie is given to the user with a random number. If I don't add this condition, the cookie number obviously randomly change with every page reload.

This is my application controller :

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
# Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
# For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
before_action :set_cookies

 private

 def set_cookies
  if !(cookies[:token].blank?)
   cookies[:token] = {
    value: SecureRandom.random_number,
    domain: "mydomain"
   }
  end
 end
end
```

With this, it seems that cookie storage just never works. I tried different ways of writing this condition. Nothing works.

I check if there is a cookie by writing this in the view :

```
    <%= cookies[:token].to_s %>
```

When I add the condition, this space is just empty.

What obvious thing am I missing here ?

EDIT: the answer doesn't seem to work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OKAY I finally got it.

I had entered an invalid domain. I just had to delete

```
    domain: "mydomain"
```

Apparently that was making everything go wrong.

Comment: I thought that "mydomain" was placeholder text so that you don't reveal your actual domain. Technically you don't even have to specify the `domain` option when setting a cookie, as the domain will be set to the one shown in the address bar, but I'm glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra negation in your condition:

```
if !(cookies[:token].blank?)
  cookies[:token] = ...
```

so that token will be set only if it is already non-blank

Comment: I tried : 

`if !(cookies[:token])`
  

to avoid replacing my cookie when there is already one, but this seems to be true all the time (the cookie number always change)

Comment: @ZerhAriel test for `if cookies[:token].blank?`

Comment: The cookie number displayed keep changing with reloads

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting a permanent cookie. Try changing this:

```
cookies[:token] = {
    value: SecureRandom.random_number,
    domain: "mydomain"
   }
```

To this:

```
cookies.permanent[:token] = {
    value: SecureRandom.random_number,
    domain: "mydomain"
   }
```

You might also want this cookie to expire after a certain amount of time. By default, the expiration date is 20 years when you use the `.permanent` method. If you wanted the cookie to expire after a day, you can do the following:

```
cookies.permanent[:token] = {
        value: SecureRandom.random_number,
        domain: "mydomain",
        expires: 1.day.from_now.utc
       }
```

Using this method of saving cookies, each new user will have a token assigned to him that won't change even if the page is reloaded or the browser is closed.

For further information, see the cookies [Reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html).

Comment: You stated that my answer did not solve your problem but marked it as an answer. Can you please mark the correct answer as the answer so that others can know what worked for you?